# Forcing label placement to be always inside polygon using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

How do I force a label to be ALWAYS INSIDE a polygon with placement method "Using perimeter (curved)"?

I experimented with "Left of line", "Right of line", but some labels are still placed outside the polygon.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can go to the label rendering pan and check the box "only draw labels that fits completely within feature"

[image]

Also make sure that the placement allows labels above and below line.

[image]